# How do I insert latex tags in stackexchange?

Tags: support

It is not listed in the full reference. But I have seen people insert latex code. Which tag is for latex?

Answer (score 9):

Just put latex code between $ signs. Like this: `$\alpha$` gives $\alpha$.

Comment: it doesnt work for me? It just stays as $...$. Is there actual tag I could use to force it to compile latex?

Comment: Stop typing and wait. The preview panel will show the rendered symbols when you pause.